# Ruby: Group array of array of object

Tags: arrays, ruby, group-by

I would like to group an array of arrays of objects by object attribute.

So, if we have

```
array =[[object1, object2], [object3], [object4, object5, object6]]
```

and this object has an attribute say "source". Now assume each object has the following source value:

```
object1> source=source1
object2> source=source2
object3> source=source2
object4> source=source1
object5> source=source1
object6> source=source3
```

I want to group the arrays that are inside "array" by source attribute.

so I would like to have:

```
source1 => [object1, object2], [object4, object5, object6]
source2 => [object1, object2] 
source3 => [object4, object5, object6]
```

for source2, I don't care about array of size 1 so I don't want to add [object3]

Any help?

Comment: can you make this 2D array to single array and then group by.?

Comment: Do you mean `array.flatten.group_by(&:source)`? Be more concise please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing, which became apparent after your edit, is that you have already grouped your objects, and you want to bucket your groups into potentially more than one bucket based on the objects in each grouping, so this isn't a pure `group_by` algorithm. Here is one possible solution:

First, create a hash to hold your groups. This sets an empty array as the default value:

```
sources = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new }
```

Then `reject` the ones you don't care about (see [Enumerable#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)).

```
array.reject{|group| group.size == 1}
```

Finally, iterate through the groups, collecting their `source`s and adding the group to the appropriate source in the hash. Full example:

```
sources = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Array.new }

array.reject{|group| group.size == 1}.each do |group|
  group.collect{|group| group.source}.uniq.each do |source|
    sources[source] << group
  end
end
```